# Iframe on bottom generate white-space after footer

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an `iframe` in the footer. If I set `height` of the `iframe` =  `height` of the footer, it generates *white-space* under the `iframe` viz ugly. You can see it here:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kpsr5L0g)

you can try setting height of the `iframe` to 275px, the ugly *white-space* is gone.

Why is this happening?
Please help.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do? I don't see any pixels under the iframe.

Comment: What browser... give me details please.

Comment: Look here https://youtu.be/lyqwrjVrvIo

Comment: Im using chrome browser.

Comment: @MilanObrtlík that's a great Solution :)

Comment: What solution? Im not showing solution, im showing problem! :D

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Here I've created a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/kpsr5L0g/2)

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-4 hasIframe">
        <iframe ...
```

**CSS**

```
.hasIframe { background: #296496; height: 280px; line-height: 0;}
.hasIframe iframe { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; width:100%; border: 1px solid #f00;}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

you can see there's no *white-space*, its just `iframe` has some default **CSS** and you've to reset its *CSS* accordingly.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: @MilanObrtlík Please check my answer again, I've made necessary changes. In my **Fiddle** there's no space now.

Comment: In Chrome 45.0.2454.99 is still 5px white space under footer.
In IE the same like Chrome.
Only in firefox its good.